# how to write continue in this way of typing "if"

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-operator

hey I want to type if statement with the way 2 but I need to put there a continue and it not working with any ideas ?
way 1 to type if

```
if ( x+2 < 0) {
    y=x+2;
}
else {
    y=-(x+2);
}
```

way 2 to type if

```
y=(x+2 < 0) ? x+2 : -(x+2)
```

my question how to type continue in the second way something like this :

```
(x==1) ? continue : x+1 ;
```

but this not working for me.

Comment: `continue` is used in *loops* to *continue* to the next loop iteration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ternary operator (`?`) just returns a value (conditionally). You can't use it to execute arbitrary blocks of code. In other words, if you need to conditionally call `continue`, you need to use an `if` structure, not a ternary.